# Excel- How to collect the max value of an array of cells dependent on one other cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a code that can sort through a couple thousand data points quickly to find the maximum value.  The data points are dependent on one cell that also needs to be evaluated through multiple values.

I've tried just using the application.worksheetfunction to sort through the data that the code generates before it moves to the next data point, but I get a "compile error: type mismatch" message.  See code:

```
Sub GenerateData()
    Dim curDataPt As Long, curVal As Long
    Dim rngOut As Range, rngIn As Range, rngData As Range, rngVar As Range

    Const maxVal As Long = 50
    Const minVal As Long = 0.02
    Const stepVal As Long = 0.01

    Set rngIn = Sheet2.Range("B10")
    Set rngOut = Sheet2.Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("H29:H1569"))
    Set rngVar = Sheet2.Range("N1")
    Set rngData = Sheet2.Range("O1")

    For curVal = minVal To maxVal Step stepVal
        curDataPt = curVal / stepVal
        rngIn = curVal
        rngVar.Offset(curDataPt) = curVal
        rngData.Offset(curDataPt) = rngOut
    Next curVal
    Sheet1.Names.Add "DataIn", rngVar.Resize(curDataPt + 1)
    Sheet1.Names.Add "DataOut", rngData.Resize(curDataPt + 1)
End Sub
```

I would like for the code to generate 5000 cell columns of rngIn, and rngOut begining at N1 & O1. The issue is in the Application.WorksheetFunction code I believe, but I don't know another way to get those values out efficiently.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:**
Some changes I've made to get the bones of the code to work and hopefully explain what I want a little better.

Here is the code I am trying to expand to get what I need:

Sub GenerateData()
    Dim curDataPt As Long, curVal As Long
    Dim rngOut As Range, rngIn As Range, rngData As Range, rngVar As Range

```
Const maxVal As Long = 10
Const minVal As Long = 1
Const stepVal As Long = 1

Set rngIn = Sheet2.Range("B6")
Set rngOut = Sheet2.Range("H40")
Set rngVar = Sheet2.Range("AB1")
Set rngData = Sheet2.Range("AC1")

For curVal = minVal To maxVal Step stepVal
    curDataPt = curVal / stepVal
    rngIn = curVal
    rngVar.Offset(curDataPt) = curVal
    rngData.Offset(curDataPt) = rngOut
Next curVal
Sheet2.Names.Add "DataIn", rngVar.Resize(curDataPt + 1)
Sheet2.Names.Add "DataOut", rngData.Resize(curDataPt + 1)
```

End Sub

When run, the code produces the list seen in image 1.

[rngIn on left, rngOut on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZudx.png)

This is in general what I want to do; however, i need my rngOUT to be the maximum value of a range that is controlled by rngIN (see image 2).

[rngOUT is in the u0 column highlighted on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d949.png)

That is why originally, I had tried to use the worksheetfunction.max command over the entire range of u0.

I also cannot figure out how to make my stepVal and minVAL  rational numbers.  This is probably something simple I'm forgetting from my one coding class 6 years ago.

Thanks again in advance.  I'm not a coder by any means, so this website teaches me a ton.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish here. One error that jumps out it the following:

```
rngIn = curVal
```

This will not work for 2 reasons: rngIn is a range, which is an object that needs to be Set. And curVal is a Long that will never fit into a Range. This error will cause the one you say you get. If you need further help, please post an example of your data, information on the worksheet function you are trying to use and information on the output you are expecting from this sub.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've tried to clear things up with an edit.